# Java check method inheritance

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

Can someone explain me why  my check method doesn't work , because i am not sure where is the mistake.

```
    Dog dogArray = new Dog();
    Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
    animals [0] = new Dog();
    animals [1] = new Cat();
    animals [2] = new Wolf();
    animals [3] = new Hippo();
    animals [4] = new Lion();
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        animals[i].eat();
        animals[i].makeNoise();
        animals[i].testPolymorphism();
        public void checkAnimals() {
            if (dogArray.equals(animals[i])) {
                            System.out.println("DogArray matches Dog i" + i);
                    }
            System.out.println("DogArray doesn't match any animal");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're declaring it inside another method. That's not going to work.

Comment: You can't create a function inside of a function.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do declaring a method just at a random place in your code, but it certainly isn't valid java.

Comment: I assume `Dog` does not overwrite `equals` so the condition will never be `true` because the instances are not the same

Comment: Тhe problem is , when it is outside the for loop can't recognize animals[i] and it's normal , but i don't know how can i fix it and also i am not sure if my logic is right

Comment: Create a regular `public void checkAnimals(Animal[] animals, Animal animal)` method and call it like  `checkAnimals(animals, dogArray);`. Note that your `Dog` object has no reason to have "array" in its name .

Comment: you are writing a checkAnimals() inside for loop. which is not correct. Is it syntax copy-paste issue or the code is really like that? It won't compile if its really inside for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the checkAnimal code inside the for loop itself. By which you do not need to write a new method and achieve the expected result.

```
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
    animals [0] = new Dog();
    animals [1] = new Cat();
    animals [2] = new Wolf();
    animals [3] = new Hippo();
    animals [4] = new Lion();

    for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        animals[i].eat();
        animals[i].makeNoise();
        animals[i].testPolymorphism();

        if (dog.equals(animals[i])) {
           System.out.println("DogArray matches Dog i" + i);
        }else{
           System.out.println("DogArray doesn't match any animal");
        } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I believe this is what you were trying to achieve.

```
    public void main() {
      //Declarations
      Dog dogArray = new Dog(); //Could call this just "dog"
      Animal[] animals = new Animal[5]; //"animalsArray" could be a suitable name

      //Populate array
      animals [0] = new Dog();
      animals [1] = new Cat();
      animals [2] = new Wolf();
      animals [3] = new Hippo();
      animals [4] = new Lion();

      //call function which you were trying to declare inside a function 
      checkAnimals(animals, dogArray);
   }

   public void checkAnimals(Animals animals, Dog dogArray) {
     //Loop through array
     for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) { 
        //Process each animal
        animals[i].eat();
        animals[i].makeNoise();
        animals[i].testPolymorphism();

        //Check if current animal is the dog
        if (dogArray.equals(animals[i])) {
          System.out.println("DogArray matches Dog i" + i);
        } else {
          System.out.println("DogArray doesn't match current animal");
        }
     }
   }
```